# Hide Floor overlay from viewport render in Blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, interface

In 2.79 *Floor grid* hides automatically when doing viewport renders, but stayed in place for solid view.

How can I obtain such behaviour in 2.8? Manual unchecking *Floor* from *Overlays* is a bit annoying

Comment: I'm afraid it's one of the features that have been dropped from `2.8+`. I don't know of any setting that allows to do that either. You're going to have to hide the grid floor manually like in one of the two answers.

Answer (score 2):

It's not automatic but I've spent a good amount of time searching for this myself and found out that you can toggle on/off all overlays (grid, outlines, etc) by clicking the overlay icon.

[image]

[image]

I know this is pretty late but I figured I'd post this in case. It's still annoying but it's better than having to uncheck/check each overlay.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide only the grids, but keep other overlays, you can expand the Overlay Icon and uncheck **Grid**, **Floor** and **Axis** :

[image]